# Why are my sorting results coming back as completely random?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

my array jokesarray has elements like the following. I am trying to sort by nested element "sec".

Everytime I run this I get a different sort order or every time I come back to the same view (my sorting code is in viewwillappear). Why?

```
    {
       "4eb57e72c7e24c014f000000" : {
         "_id" : {
           "$id" : "4eb57e72c7e24c014f000000"
         },
         "author" : "tim",
         "comments" : [],
         "created": {
           "sec" : 1320517234,
           "used" : 856000
         },
         "picture" : "http://someurl.com",
         "text" : "this is a test",
         "title" : "test",
         "type" : ["test"]
       }

    jokesArray = [unSortedContentArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:Sort_Created_Comparer context:self]; 

    NSInteger Sort_Created_Comparer(id array1, id array2, void *context)
{

    int v1 = (int)[[array1 objectForKey:@"created"] objectForKey:@"sec"];
    int v2 = (int)[[array2 objectForKey:@"created"] objectForKey:@"sec"];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[[array1 objectForKey:@"created"] objectForKey:@"sec"]
```

returns a pointer to an object; in your case, an `NSNumber` object. When you cast it to `int` like:

```
(int)[[array1 objectForKey:@"created"] objectForKey:@"sec"]
```

you’re casting the memory address where that object is located to an `int` value, since `-objectForKey:` returns a pointer to an object.

As you’re not interested in the memory address but the underlying `int` value instead, use `-[NSNumber intValue]`:

```
int v1 = [[[array1 objectForKey:@"created"] objectForKey:@"sec"] intValue];
```

Also, it’s odd that you’ve named your dictionaries `array1` and `array2` — they aren’t arrays.

---

**Edit:** Alternatively, you could let `NSNumber` do the comparison for you:

```
NSInteger Sort_Created_Comparer(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2, void *context)
{
    NSNumber *n1 = [[d1 objectForKey:@"created"] objectForKey:@"sec"];
    NSNumber *n2 = [[d2 objectForKey:@"created"] objectForKey:@"sec"];
    return [n1 compare:n2];
}
```

Comment: Bavarious: as always you have been very helpful. Thank You sir

Answer (score 2):

Method `-objectForKey:` returns a `NSNumber` object pointer. It cannot be directly cast to number, call `[NSNumber intValue]` to get the value of this object.

However, probably you may want to do that simpler:

```
jokesArray = [unSortedContentArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:
               [[NSSortDescriptor initWithKey:@"created.sec"
                                    ascending:YES] autorelease]]];
```